# Return Array Instead of String

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get an array response from my `getTeam()` function so I can properly filter my DataTable to show more than one team for the current Player (if they are on more than one team).

DataTables Filter:

```js
  $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push( //creating my own filter function for the table
        function(settings, searchData, index, rowData, counter, statusClass) { 

            var userName = searchData[1]; //created a var to search through the 3rd column (0 index) which contains all of the Monday Dates
            var searchTeam = searchData[0];
            // Get Datatables API
            var api = $.fn.dataTable.Api('#myTable'); 
            if (settings.sTableId === 'myTable' ) {
            if(userName === thisUserTitle){
            return true;
            } else {
              return false;
           }
           
          }
          if (settings.sTableId === 'certificateTable' ) {
            if(currentTeam === searchTeam){
            return true;
            } else {
              return false;
           }
           
          }
          return true;
        }
    );
```

The original snippet that returns just the first team:

```js
var teamData = [{
  "Team" : "Team 1",
  "Players" :[ 
    "Beerus Dev",
    "Goten Dev",
    "Trunks Dev",
    "Majin Bu Dev"

  ]
},
{
  "Team" : "Team 2",
  "Players" : [
    "Beerus Dev",
    "Shap Dev",
    "Krillin Dev"
  ]
}
];


function getTeam() {

  const team = teamData.find(team => team.Players.includes(currentUser));
  return team.Team;
}

var currentUser = "Beerus Dev";
var currentTeam = getTeam(currentUser);
 
console.log(currentTeam);
```

To get the array response, I have tried using the `.filter()` as opposed to the `.find()` but I end up getting an empty array as my response.

```js
var teamData = [{
  "Team" : "Team 1",
  "Players" :[ 
    "Beerus Dev",
    "Goten Dev",
    "Trunks Dev",
    "Majin Bu Dev"

  ]
},
{
  "Team" : "Team 2",
  "Players" : [
    "Beerus Dev",
    "Shap Dev",
    "Krillin Dev"
  ]
}
];

var currentUser = "Beerus Dev";

const team = teamData.filter(function(team, i){
    return teamData[i].Players.includes(currentUser);
})

console.log(team)
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo on my part. That provides a response, but it returns the entire teamData instead of for in this example ["Team 1", "Team 2"]

Comment: i ran that code exactly as you posted (the filter version), and got an array with two entries in it.  There must be something broken in your code somewhere else.  This code works.

Comment: You can try `reduce`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplify this code:

```js
var teamData = [{
  "Team" : "Team 1",
  "Players" :[ 
    "Beerus Dev",
    "Goten Dev",
    "Trunks Dev",
    "Majin Bu Dev"

  ]
},
{
  "Team" : "Team 2",
  "Players" : [
    "Beerus Dev",
    "Shap Dev",
    "Krillin Dev"
  ]
}
];

var currentUser = "Beerus Dev";
const team = teamData.filter(team => team.Players.includes(currentUser)).map(team => team.Team);

console.log(team)
```

Comment: Or even further: `filter(({ Players }) => Players.includes(currentUser))`. This doesn't really answer the question tho

Comment: There is no limit to refactor))

Comment: See this returns the entire dataset I am trying to filter from, I need to get `Team 1, Team 2` as the only items returned.

Comment: Just saw your edit, this is exactly what I was trying to do. Many thanks

Comment: You are welcome))